# Selenium Webdriver find Element using Java

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium

Can anyone solve this problem?

Class names are same. I dont want to use Xpath. The only difference is in aria-controls as shown below in html. What should i be doing to find element and take click on the tabs?

```
<li class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope resp-tab-item resp-tab-active" ng-model="danceCat.category" ng-init="$last ? checklast() : null" ng-repeat="danceCat in dancestyles.data.learn" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab"> A

<li class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope resp-tab-item" ng-model="danceCat.category" ng-init="$last ? checklast() : null" ng-repeat="danceCat in dancestyles.data.learn" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab"> B

<div class="dance_style_number ng-binding" align="right">3</div>
```

```
<li class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope resp-tab-item" ng-model="danceCat.category" ng-init="$last ? checklast() : null" ng-repeat="danceCat in dancestyles.data.learn" aria-controls="tab_item-2" role="tab"> C

<div class="dance_style_number ng-binding" align="right">2</div>
```

```
<li class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope resp-tab-item" ng-model="danceCat.category" ng-init="$last ? checklast() : null" ng-repeat="danceCat in dancestyles.data.learn" aria-controls="tab_item-3" role="tab"> D

<li class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope resp-tab-item" ng-model="danceCat.category" ng-init="$last ? checklast() : null" ng-repeat="danceCat in dancestyles.data.learn" aria-controls="tab_item-4" role="tab"> E
```

Comment: Have you tried any selenium code from your site? Also what is reason that you do not want to use xpath?

Comment: I would normally add ids and use that to locate the elements

Comment: I want to know if i can use any alternatives other than xpath.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use css selector this would propably work

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[aria-controls='tab_item-1']"));
```